# sticky keys do not work on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome

I upgraded my system today.Sticky keys stop working.

It must be a anonymous bug.What can I do?

best regards.

Comment: Is it the same problem both in Wayland and in Xorg?

Comment: @sudodus: Only Wayland, I think. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a Wayland related issue. You can log in to an "Ubuntu on Xorg" session instead of just "Ubuntu".

Reported as [bug #1727716](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1727716).